# How to destroy breakable wall above me?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I have just defeated Ra's and as I'm heading back to exit wonder tower I come across a breakable wall above my head and there is no way for me to reach it. I'm so confused. The worse part is I can't even continue the game without breaking this wall. And the thing is, I already broke this wall as I was entering wonder tower, but now it's back? And I can't break it? It's sooo stupid.

Comment: Should be possible to spray explosive gel onto a nearby ceiling, or glide and use the launcher to propel yourself upwards. May also be an alternative path, especially on Wonder Tower. Don't have a PC to test this, currently.

Answer (score 1):

You don't break the ceiling from the room you're in, you break it from the room above it, later on in the game.
For now, after defeating Ra's, exit the tower from the other side of the main room.
During a later mission, you will be able to enter the room above, hit the riddler switch and use explosive gel on the floor.
I don't remember exactly, but I think it's after you get the zip-line gadget.